# Cómo hacer para evitar ingresar un valor que ya está dentro de diccionarios en diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo estos diccionarios de diccionarios

```
{'IDA': '01', 'Curso': {'ID': '02', 'Nombre': 'INTRODUCCION AL SISTEMA ADUANERO', 'Codigo': 'AA-114'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '02', 'Nombre': 'Administracion y Gestion de Recursos Humanos ', 'Codigo': 'AGRH'}}
```

```
{'IDA': '02', 'Curso': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'METODOS DE INVESTIGACION', 'Codigo': 'AA-113'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'Administracion Aduanera', 'Codigo': 'AA'}}
```

```
{'IDA': '03', 'Curso': {'ID': '45', 'Nombre': 'PRONUNCIACION', 'Codigo': 'ILE-214'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '05', 'Nombre': 'Contabilidad y Finanzas ', 'Codigo': 'COFI'}}
```

```
{'IDA': '04', 'Curso': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'METODOS DE ESCRITURA', 'Codigo': 'AA-113'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'Administracion Aduanera', 'Codigo': 'AA'}}
```

y quiero ingresar más datos, pero ¿cómo valido que si ingreso un curso y si ya está en alguno de los diccionarios no me deje?

Answer (score 1):

Por empezar especificaría un poco mejor tu pregunta, poniendo un ejemplo que sea reproducible, por ahora tengo que asumir cosas que no están en la pregunta y no sé si es efectivamente es lo que estás requiriendo.

- Tenemos 4 objetos de tipo diccionario (con diccionarios en ellos)
- aparece un `nuevocurso` que es un diccionario también
- Recorro los 4 objetos y verifico el diccionario `Curso` si es el mismo que quier ingresar, sino error y salgo del ciclo.

..

```
d1 = {'IDA': '01', 'Curso': {'ID': '02', 'Nombre': 'INTRODUCCION AL SISTEMA ADUANERO', 'Codigo': 'AA-114'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '02', 'Nombre': 'Administracion y Gestion de Recursos Humanos ', 'Codigo': 'AGRH'}}
d2 = {'IDA': '02', 'Curso': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'METODOS DE INVESTIGACION', 'Codigo': 'AA-113'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'Administracion Aduanera', 'Codigo': 'AA'}}
d3 = {'IDA': '03', 'Curso': {'ID': '45', 'Nombre': 'PRONUNCIACION', 'Codigo': 'ILE-214'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '05', 'Nombre': 'Contabilidad y Finanzas ', 'Codigo': 'COFI'}}
d4 = {'IDA': '04', 'Curso': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'METODOS DE ESCRITURA', 'Codigo': 'AA-113'}, 'Carrera': {'ID': '01', 'Nombre': 'Administracion Aduanera', 'Codigo': 'AA'}}

nuevocurso = {'ID': '02', 'Nombre': 'INTRODUCCION AL SISTEMA ADUANERO', 'Codigo': 'AA-114'}
existe = False
for d in [d1,d2,d3,d4]:
    if nuevocurso == d["Curso"]:
        existe = True
        break
if existe:
    print("El curso {} ya existe".format(nuevocurso))
else:
    # Hago lo que tengo que hacer
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo, vista la relativa complejidad de la estructura te animaría a crear una clase.
Dentro de la clase podrías definir una función que se ocupara de comprobar que el valor no está duplicado.